# Google Group not receiving emails from SendGrid

Tags: gmail, sendgrid

I have a Google Group setup called `tes@domain.com` on my G-mail Account.

In that group, I have 8 members email addresses.

If I send mail to that group from "send-grid", the mail is not been received.

```
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
```

On Send-grid when I check status of this group-email(tes@domain.com) its show its been "Delivered" and "Opened" as well.

And I also get this SendGrid `{"message":"success"}` json response

Comment: Any error code to post?

Comment: Like I said, I get success in response. No Error. Also in Send-Grid dashboard it shows Mail been "Delivered" and "Opened". But the mail is not getting sent to the people in the group.

Answer (score 1):

Your group email alias is probably not enabled to receive emails from external sources. You need to update your settings to allow posts from 'anyone'